# Alternative definitions of functions requiring non-empty domains?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, definition

It is easy enough to prove in set theory, but it seems counter-intuitive to me that an empty set could be the domain of a function. Is there any literature requiring that functions have non-empty domains?

**EDIT**

I mean definitions something like...

For all sets $B$ and *non-empty* $A$, $f$ is a function mapping $A$ to $B$ iff

1) $f\subset A\times B$

2) $\forall x\in A: \exists y\in B: (x,y)\in f$

3) $\forall x,y_1,y_2:[ (x,y_1)\in f \land (x,y_2)\in f \implies y_1=y_2]$

Comment: Mathematics is in desperate need of an [anti-psychologist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-psychologism) trend.

Comment: You should edit "an empty set could be a function" to "an empty set could be a domain of a function."

Comment: @Joel: The usual set-theoretic way to *represent* a function is by its graph. Any function whose domain is the empty set has a graph that is also the empty set.

Comment: Of course, if you disallow the empty function, then the empty set could not be said to have the same cardinality _as itself_, unless you further complicate the definition of the equipotence relation to explicitly mention this case.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Done. Thanks.

Comment: @Hurkyl, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4):

I honestly can't think of any literature off the top of my head with that restriction. Note that by allowing the empty set to be the domain of functions, you make the empty set an initial object in the category of sets.

Comment: Interesting. A number of other key notions seem to hinge on it as well. Best not to open that Pandora's box, I guess.

Comment: Even worse, if you forbid functions with empty domains, you *don't* have a category of sets, because such a thing would need an identity function from the empty set to itself!

Comment: @Hurkyl That would be a catastrophe! Wouldn't it?  ;^)

Comment: @Hurkyl There I go forgetting the obvious, again.